# Alarm manager triggers just after alarm set

Tags: android

I am working on app in which I want to set alarm on weekly basis, e.g. on every sunday 10:00pm or every sunday and monday on 10:00pm. but whenever I start alarm manager it triggers immediately, I know that I am creating an alarm for the day which has passed but I still want to add alarm for next coming sunday, and I am unable to achieve that. here is a code what I have done so far.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SchedulerReciever.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), i, intent, 0);

intentArray.add(pendingIntent1);
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

Long alarmTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7,alarmTime, pendingIntent1);
```

Comment: sorry for above two lines,they are part of my code

Comment: Your `Calendar` is set to a value in the past.

Comment: i know that but i want to set alarm for next sunday and it should repeat on every sunday after that, until user cancel it explicitly.

Comment: Add 7 days to the `Calendar` value, to push it to next week.

Comment: how to add 7 days to Calendar value? i have already added AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7 into that.

Comment: ``calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY+7)``

Comment: will this code work for every coming sundays?

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 7)`.

Comment: Heikki Mäenpää's code not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550991/repeating-alarm-for-specific-days-of-week-android check out this link @hanzalaansari