# How to send notification without being online?

Tags: android, notifications

I am building an app that a user will put their tests and assignments and whatever in. I want to know will it be possible for my app to bring up a notification like a week and a day before the test?

Everywhere I look its just about firebase notifications and push notifications.

I don't want these online notification, I'll need the app to send them by itself offline. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to use the AlaramManager for it

Comment: Yes you can trigger local push notification by sceduling time with alarm manager..

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Thank you, I appreciate the response. Any place you know of that has a good tutorial or somewhere with good insight on how to do it?

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha Thank you as well, only saw your comment when I scrolled up, please see my above comment.

Comment: see http://droidmentor.com/schedule-notifications-using-alarmmanager/ for reference

Comment: @Erbez Please have a look on this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36550991/repeating-alarm-for-specific-days-of-week-android

Comment: @Erbez Check my answer will help you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me add some workaround you can find more tutorial outside..

First create receiver class extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class ReminderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int Request_Code = intent.getExtras().getInt("TIME",0);
    showNotification(context, MainActivity.class,
            "New Notification Alert..!", "scheduled for " + Request_Code + " seconds",Request_Code);
}

public void showNotification(Context context, Class<?> cls, String title, String content,int RequestCode)
{
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(cls);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            RequestCode,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = context.getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,"my_channel_01");
    Notification notification = builder.setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content).setAutoCancel(true)
       .setSound(alarmSound).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();


    notificationManager.notify(RequestCode,notification);
}

}
```

Declare receiver in manifest class below activity tag..

```
 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".ReminderReceiver"/>
```

Then set reminder to alarm manager.

```
 public void setReminder(Context context,Class<?> cls,int sec)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
        intent.putExtra("TIME",sec);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, sec, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);/* Find more about flags: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent */

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set( AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (sec * 1000), pendingIntent );//Add time in milliseconds. if you want to minute or hour mutiply by 60.. For ex: You want to trigger 5 Min then here you need to change 5 * 60 * 1000


}
```

Finally set your reminder

```
setReminder(_Context,ReminderReceiver.class,time);
```

**Updated**

**For support android version 8.0 and above you have to create notification channel. Find more here** [Manage Channels](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels)

Add this in above code:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = context.getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = context.getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("my_channel_01", name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
```

> Note use drawable for small icons not use mipmap or adaptive icons.[Android Oreo Notification Crashes System UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368187/android-oreo-notification-crashes-system-ui)

**To Cancel the scheduled notification**

```
 public void cancelReminder(Context context,Class<?> cls)
{
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
    intent1.putExtra("TIME",time);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
            time, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    if(pendingIntent != null) {
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And use above method to delete

```
cancelReminder(_Context,ReminderReceiver.class);
```

> Note: _Context should be same as used in `setreminder()` method

Comment: Hi, I've followed your code. I do not get notifications though. I uploaded a RAR of my project, could you please check what I did wrong? Thank you. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lhCIxLpF_JSvsBa_a-fu1X_ZfAUpqGrW

Comment: The floating action button has the set `setReminder(_Context,ReminderReceiver.class,time);` in it

Comment: Which version of api you are checking?

Comment: `minSdkVersion 22`, `targetSdkVersion 27` and `compileSdkVersion 27`. I am testing on a Huawei P10 with android 8.

Comment: For me its working i change minapi 21 for checking... Its working

Comment: The RAR I uploaded? or did you make your own application?

Comment: I tested your code only its working fine.. [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPegr.gif)

Comment: I changed it to min `minSdkVersion 21` and still not. I wonder why.

Comment: Check with emulator or other device if you have may be device is problem..

Comment: You have to work on notificaion channels from 8.0 you can find more here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels

Comment: I just wanted to ask, will this last as long as the app is installed, so if I put the notification for 3 months later, will it show 3 months later?

Comment: Yes you can get notification as long as app installed  also check here lifecycle of pending intent and alarm with detailed explanation http://luboganev.github.io/post/alarms-pending-intent/

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Sorry to bother, is there a way to cancel the notification created?

Comment: @Cleaven Yes you can check the updated code will help you..!

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Sorry it didn't work, i posted a question if you are interested :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645365/disable-stored-reminder-alarmmanager-type

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Hi, I just wanted to know which part of the notification opens my app, if I clear all notifications, the app opens, I don't want that.

Comment: @Erbez You should aware of pending intent lifecycle make sure you cancel also the pending intent after cancel alarm manager intent. Find more here http://luboganev.github.io/post/alarms-pending-intent/

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read [Notifications Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications). This well help you to understand how notification works.

To now build the notification, here is the [Here is the official documentation for notification](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification).

Read and understand. When you encounter any problem then, you can come back here for the solution.