# Android notification reminder on specific date and time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to add a reminder scheduler in my app on selected date and time. Basically a task reminder with notifications. I have created a dialog for selecting date and time, I am not able to understand how to go further being new to android. I understand that I will need an AlarmManager and Receiver class. I saw a lot of tutorials but couldn't very well understand. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179366/4824088

Comment: You should instead read the docs for AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver on the Developer Website. Lots of useful details on the developer.android.com

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This reminds after particular seconds, how do i modify it for specific  date and time?

Comment: I figured out! Thanks for the help!