# How to set multiple local notification in background in android?

Tags: android, push-notification, alarm, background-service

i want to triggering multiple notifications from my mobile 
when i started my app i have to set notifications in different times after that time its need to trigger notification for ex i have set a notification at 8:30,8:40
if i closed the app i need to show that notifications i tried some code but its triggering only first one here my code

```
       public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Toast.makeText(context, "ALARM!! ALARM!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Stop sound service to play sound for alarm
  //  context.startService(new Intent(context, AlarmSoundService.class));

    //This will send a notification message and show notification in 
          notification tray
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmNotificationService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));

          }
          }
```

////////

```
     public void setalrm(List<String> times)
{

    AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) 
  this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();

    for(int i = 0; i < times.size(); i++)
    {
        String time="";
        SimpleDateFormat sd=   new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss", 
    Locale.getDefault());
        String[] ss;

        time=times.get(i);
        ss=time.split(":");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(ss[0]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(ss[1]));
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("text","set");
        intent.putExtra("time",time);
     // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, 
     intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) 
       getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);//get instance of alarm 
       manager
        //set alarm manager with entered timer by converting into 
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

       mgrAlarm.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
         calendar.getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {

      mgrAlarm.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
       pendingIntent);
        } else {
            mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.
     getTimeInMillis(),pendingIntent);
        }


        intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

//////

```
    public class AlarmNotificationService extends IntentService {
   private NotificationManager alarmNotificationManager;

//Notification ID for Alarm
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

public AlarmNotificationService() {
    super("AlarmNotificationService");
}

@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    //Send notification
    sendNotification("Wake Up! Wake Up! Alarm started!!");
}

//handle notification
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    alarmNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //get pending intent
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //Create notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder alamNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setContentTitle("Alarm").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.em_logo)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg).setAutoCancel(true);
    alamNotificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    //notiy notification manager about new notification
    alarmNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, 
    alamNotificationBuilder.build());
}


  }
```

Comment: You have to set unique ID for notification in your code `NOTIFICATION_ID` & use FLAG_ONE_SHOT for mutiple notification.[See Here Also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52179366/4824088)

Comment: thank you bro its working fine now

Comment: Welcome glad to help happy coding :)

Comment: in redmi phones i'm not getting notification do you have any idea